# Classification Problem with large number of predictors and huge training data

Tags: logistic, classification, feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction, high-dimensional

I have a classification problem with over 700 predictor variables and training data with 200,000 observations. There is only one response variable.

I have a feature selection problem. I am looking for techniques to determine out of the 700 predictors, which are relevant for the model. I am aware of some techniques such as regularization (Lasso and Ridge) and PCA, but not sure which technique would be feasible for my dataset.

Also, are there any packages in R that can help me achieve this?

Thanks,
Gaerik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one package Boruta in r which basically use random forest alongwith with wrapper approach to calculate the importance of different features. Feature Importance is calculated using permutation importance. You need to have "ranger" package as well to install Boruta package. 
Following link might be helpful:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Boruta/Boruta.pdf

Comment: Thanks! Does does this approach provides only the most important independent features OR does it provide a set of features that work well as a combination?
Also,  with over 700 predictor variables and 200000 observations, is this computationally heavy?

Comment: This thing will provide you the importance of all the features. It will calculate score for each feature and will sort them in descending order based on there score. It might be computationally heavy.

Answer (score 1):

As it is a supervised problem, you can use Fisher Score for feature selection. It helps you to prune the dataset distinguishing which variables affect more to your labels (in order to differentiate them).

For feature extraction you can use LDA(Linear Discrimnant Analysis) that finds a projection that maximizes the distance between labeled groups and helps the posterior classifier algorithm. It is also useful for data visualization.

These are two examples for feature selection and feature extraction approaches. They can be useful with supervised problems but exist lots of other algorithms that help with the classification task.

Comment: Thanks! Apologies for my lack of limited understanding of this subject - I believe that the Fisher score will only provide me the set of predictors that could be important if used independently. How do I check if a combination of variables, say a and b, that are not important predictors by themselves but good predictors when used together?

Comment: Hi! When you apply any feature extraction technique the resulting projection  can be translated to a new set of features ( a kind of "combination"). You can skip the selection part(to preserve all the features) and tackle directly the extraction one. I don't know if it helps, if I'm honest I don't know any selection technique that performs what you want. Hope somedoby else could answer...

Comment: Understood! That really helps. I have some direction now and should be good to get started and try different things